# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch NODE on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

Please my application is unable to run on heroku, heroku is unable to bind to the host port.

I always get `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

I need help in resolving this issue.

My `index.js` code is presented below.

```
import http from 'http';
import app from './app';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer(app);
console.log('PORT: ', PORT)
server.listen(PORT,'0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log(`server listening on localhost: ${PORT}`);
});
```

node: 12.16.1
npm: 6.13.4

I have also tried solutions presented online but all to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to increase boot timeout on Heroku [here](https://tools.heroku.support/limits/boot_timeout) to the maximum (120 s for free plans).

I had the same problem but on a Springboot Application. It spent more than 60 s to connect to the database and it couldn't bind in time (< 60 s) to the $PORT.